# Floating Action Button expansion

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

According to the new [Android Design Guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions) for the Floating Action Button, it should be reasonable to [transform the Floating Action Button into a Toolbar](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsVWZpVkdpb09qREE/components-buttons-fab-transition_toolbar_01_xhdpi_002.webm).

Are there any samples / examples to perform such a transformation?

Comment: You can use the reveal animation.  On click of the fab you can start the animation to show the toolbar you want. Of course the fab will have only that function.

Comment: try to see my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use reveal animation you need add a onLayoutChange listener to the view in onCreateView callback like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_list, container, false);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                    v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
                    revealView(view);
                }
            });
        }
        return view;
    }
```

where the revealView() method will be:

```
private void revealView(View view) {

    toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);

    int cx = (view.getLeft() + view.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (view.getTop() + view.getBottom()) / 2;
    float radius = Math.max(infoContainer.getWidth(), infoContainer.getHeight()) * 2.0f;

    if (infoContainer.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        infoContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(infoContainer, cx, cy, 0, radius).start();
    } else {
        Animator reveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                infoContainer, cx, cy, radius, 0);
        reveal.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        reveal.start();
    }
}
```

In this way you should be able to create your animation. This is the way to use it. Just apply this at your fab onClick() method

Comment: This looks good. I'll test it ASAP.

Comment: Nice, let me know ;)

Comment: I don't have time right now to test it, but reading through your code the circular reveal looks like it is what I need.

Comment: can you please add some xml to your answer? I can't understand some variables.

Comment: What is infoContainer ?

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like a [Circular Reveal Animation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal) which uncovers a custom Toolbar.

Comment: That looks like what the other answer does, thanks for the reference!